# useReducer/useState updates too slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to remove redux of our application. To do so I try to use the new React Hooks API.

I wrote my own hook which is an extension of the `useReducer` function, to persist the state each time its updating.

```
export default (reducer, persistKey, onRehydrate) => {
  let initialState = rehydrate(persistKey)
  if (onRehydrate && typeof onRehydrate === 'function') {
    initialState = onRehydrate(initialState)
  }
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  function dispatch (action) {
    const nextState = reducer(state, action)
    setState(nextState)
    persist(nextState, persistKey)
  }

  return [state, dispatch]
}
```

My problem is that I have use case where my dispatch function is called several times within a short interval which are relaying on each other. Like an array which always gets a new item added on each dispatch. To do so I merge the last state and the new state. Since it's getting called before the state has updated the last state isn't the new state of the last call. Therefore my state only saves the last dispatch. 
Is there any way to solve that (besides changing the way the updates are called since they are from a thirdparty component)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to throttle/debounce when multiple useReducer calls are triggered in a short time. Because each state update will trigger a render. Instead, debounce your useReducer calls and update the state only for your latest invocation.

Comment: The problem with that is is that I need each update not just the last one and also each update is depending on the previous update so neither debouncing or throttling would help in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't verify whether this works, but I suspect it will. You could change your `setState` call within `dispatch` to the callback form, which allows you to reference the existing state before passing it into your reducer.

```
export default (reducer, persistKey, onRehydrate) => {
  let initialState = rehydrate(persistKey)
  if (onRehydrate && typeof onRehydrate === 'function') {
    initialState = onRehydrate(initialState)
  }
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  function dispatch (action) {
    setState(prevState => { // Use callback form here.
      const nextState = reducer(prevState, action)
      persist(nextState, persistKey)
      return nextState
    });
  }

  return [state, dispatch]
}
```

Comment: Didn't even know about the possibility to update the state like that. Thanks!